# What is the funtional-style replacement of this loop?

Tags: python, functional-programming, procedural-programming

I have the following loop:

```
import random
distribution = []
sum = 0
while True:
  item = random.randint(1, 8)
  if sum + item == 812:
    distribution.append(item)
    break
  elif sum + item > 812:
    distribution.append(812 - sum)
    break
  else:
    distribution.append(item)
    sum = sum + item
```

The idea here is to create a list with items where each item is a random number between 1 and 8 and the sum of items in the list has to be exactly 812. The challenge is, that the last item can randomly overshoot, so a simple stop condition won't do.

I'm racking my brain on how to express this functionally, but came up blank so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering the title of this question:

> What is the functional-style replacement of this loop?

```
def random_list(sum_rest):
    item = random.randint(1, min(8, sum_rest))
    return ([] if sum_rest - item == 0 else random_list(sum_rest - item)) + [item]
```

This solution is based on the improvement proposed by @DollarAkshay, once you get that, it is very straightforward: I am recursively calling `random_list`, but decreasing the `sum_rest` parameter by the item randomly chosen.

You get the list by calling

```
random_list(812)
```

Answer (score 2):

A disciplined (and practical) approach is to generate sequences, stopping when the sum is at least 812, and then restarting if the sum is above 812. This is called "rejection sampling". This guarantees that you are picking sequences fairly, and not skewing the randomness.

You expect approximately 1 in 8 of the samples to be good, so you expect to generate 8 samples before you find a good one.

```
import random

def seqsum(n):
    while True:
        S = 0
        s = []
        while S < n:
            s.append(random.randrange(8)+1)
            S += s[-1]
        if S == n:
            return s

for _ in range(10):
    print(seqsum(812))
```

Obviously this will be slower than skewing the last element or elements of the sequence to force the sum, but that's a trade-off for avoiding the skew.

Here's some code that prints out the distribution of the last element of the sequence, using this method, that of @hiro-protagonist and that of @DollarAkshay. It shows the frequencies of the numbers 1 to 8 in a sample of size 10000, printed as an array. You can see the heavy skew towards low numbers in those methods.

```
def seqhiro(n):
    S = 0
    s = []
    while S < n:
        s.append(min(812 - S, random.randint(1, 8)))
        S += s[-1]
    return s

def seqdollar(n):
    S = 0
    s = []
    while S < n:
        s.append(random.randint(1, min(8, 812 - S)))
        S += s[-1]
    return s

def sample(m):
    last = [0] * 9
    for _ in range(10000):
        s = m(812)
        last[s[-1]] += 1
    return last[1:]

print('rejection', sample(seqsum))
print('hiro', sample(seqhiro))
print('dollar', sample(seqdollar))
```

Output:

```
rejection [1234, 1308, 1280, 1178, 1246, 1247, 1257, 1250]
hiro [2226, 1904, 1727, 1319, 1077, 895, 560, 292]
dollar [5220, 1803, 938, 595, 475, 393, 319, 257]
```

Dollar Akshay's method produces 1 as the final number approximately 20 times more than 8, and hiro's method is better, but still 1 appears approximately  7.5 times more often than 8 as the final entry.

The method of this answer (rejection sampling) gives an approximately equal distribution for all final digits in this sample of 10000 runs.

Obviously it's possible to hide the skew of the fast methods, for example by shuffling the array before returning it, but the statistically correct method in this answer has nothing to hide.

Comment: great answer! i agree: rejection sampling is the way to go if you want a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to generate random numbers such that they do not cross `812`. For example when your sum is `806` you can only generate numbers between `[1, 6]`.

So you should change your random number generator to be

```
item = random.randint(1, min(8, 812 - sum))
```

Also your entire program becomes much shorter. **Note do not use the variable name `sum` as it is an inbuilt function**

```
import random
distribution = []
list_sum = 0
while list_sum < 812:
    item = random.randint(1, min(8, 812 - list_sum ))
    distribution.append(item)
    list_sum += item
```

Answer (score 1):

this is exactly what your `if` statements do - just rewritten with `min`:

```
MAX = 812
distribution = []
s = 0
while s < MAX:
    item = min(MAX - s, random.randint(1, 8))
    distribution.append(item)
    s += item
```

note that this will slightly skew your distribution. the last number will be consistently smaller than the others... one way to hide that a little would be to shuffle the list afterwards.

in order to have a really uniform distribution you'd have to start over in case you overshoot...

Answer (score 0):

An answer that's similar to yours

```
import random
distribution = []
lsum = 0
while True:
    item = random.randint(1, 8)
    lsum = lsum + item
    distribution.append(item)
    if lsum > 812:
        lsum = lsum - item
        distribution.pop()
    if lsum == 812:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you know the max value of items added, could you not just deterministically end with the last item as soon as you are within range of this max value at the end? In that case, you could do something like:

```
import random

def creat_random_list(total_sum, min_value=1, max_value=8):
    distribution = []
    current_sum = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        if total_sum - current_sum <= max_value:
            new_item = total_sum - current_sum
            done = True
        else:
            new_item = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
        distribution.append(new_item)
        current_sum += new_item
    return distribution


random_numers = creat_random_list(total_sum=812)
print(f"sum {sum(random_numers)} of list {random_numers}")
```

Note that I have renamed your variable sum to current sum, because sum is an inbuilt function, so not a good variable name to pick

Result look like:

```
sum 812 of list [7, 5, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 1, 2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 8, 8, 6, 5, 5, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 8, 6, 2, 6, 7, 4, 7, 7, 8, 7, 1, 4, 7, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7, 6, 8, 5, 3, 5, 4, 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 7, 1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 8, 8, 7, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 5, 6, 5, 6, 8, 5, 7, 2, 2, 8, 5, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 1, 1, 4, 8, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 7, 8, 1, 1, 8, 2, 7, 7, 2, 5, 1, 7, 7, 2, 3, 7, 7]
```